# LINQ to Entities .Concat() on two IQueryables throws NullReferencesException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following abstraction:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> Entities { get; }
}
```

with the following closed implementation:

```
public class CustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer>
{
    private readonly MyDbContext dbContext;

    public CustomerRepository(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IQueryable<Customer> Entities => InternalCustomers.Concat(ExternalCustomers);

    private IQueryable<Customer> InternalCustomers =>
        from customer in dbContext.InternalCustomers
        select new Customer
        {
            Id = customer.Id,
            Name = customer.Name
            Company = new Company
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Company",
            },
        };

    private IQueryable<Customer> ExternalCustomers =>
        from customer in dbContext.ExternalCustomers
        select new Customer
        {
            Id = customer.Id,
            Name = customer.Name
            Company = new Company
            {
                Id = customer.Company.Id,
                Name = customer.Company.Name,
            },
        };
}
```

I've omitted redundant properties and simplified this example to stress out the problem.

The class `Customer` is a custom [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (I'm mapping EntityFramework's entities *`.InternalCustomers` and `.ExternalCustomers`*) to my own custom DTO's, which can be simplified like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*I'd like to **note** out that all the properties in the `select` are set in the correct order.*

When executing the `.Entities` query, I'm getting a `NullReferenceException`, which is thrown from `EntitiyFramework.dll`, with the following top stacktrace:

```
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitSetOp(SetOp op, Node n, AliasGenerator alias, Func`3 setOpExpressionBuilder)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(UnionAllOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.UnionAllOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(FilterOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(ConstrainedSortOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ConstrainedSortOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.VisitAsRelOp(Node inputNode)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.BuildProjection(Node relOpNode, IEnumerable`1 projectionVars)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator.Visit(PhysicalProjectOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CTreeGenerator..ctor(Command itree, Node toConvert)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.ProviderCommandInfoUtils.Create(Command command, Node node)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.CodeGen.Process(List`1& childCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(DbCommandTree ctree, List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
```

As you can see, the exception message and stacktrace do not help me. Especially with the 'magic' expression trees that LINQ to Entities is building, it's a dazzling puzzle (at least for me) to investigate.

So I did some minor tweaks to the Repository implementation and I've came to the following observation:

1. When executing *only* InternalCustomers, I get a valid list from the database.
2. When executing *only* ExternalCustomers, I also get a valid list from the database.
3. The exception seems to be occurring when I use the .Concat() method.
4. The exception does **not** occur when I have the following code snippet for ExternalContacts:

Code snippet:

```
Company = new Company
{
    Id = 0, //random number
    Name = "Hello",
},
```

I'm getting a strong impression that this might be a bug in Entity Framework **6.1.3**, but I'm not sure. I'd like to know if this is indeed a bug or that I'm doing something stupid which I can't figure out after 3 hours worth of investigation.

Comment: @DanielLorenz Not unless there are duplicates in the tables that need to be removed.  I suspect that there aren't duplicates at all, and so there's no need to go out of your way to check for them.

Comment: @DanielLorenz No, it wouldn't.  That code is never run, it's just used to build expressions that are translated into SQL, and SQL propagates null values when dereferenced, rather than throwing.

Comment: Exactly what @Servy says on both questions. I've already tried `.Union()` which behaves in the same way as `.Concat()` (as in throws the same exception), but the idea here should simply be a concatenation.

Comment: Just humor me and do .Include on ExternalCustomers for Company.  It is possible that Concat here ends up running in memory instead of on sql server.  You'd have to see the SQL going over the wire to see what it was doing specifically.  Unless the SQL doesn't even make it across the wire?

Comment: Actually, what does DbContext get disposed here.  Since you are returniing IQueryable on Entities, what is that caller doing with it?  .ToList() right away?

Comment: @DanielLorenz The caller is executing the query before the DbContext gets disposed.

Comment: @DanielLorenz I've just run SQL Profiler to see what SQL gets executed by EF and as expected: **none**. @Servy explains the reasoning in the above comments. I've also tried your suggestion and did `.Include()`, which resulted in the exact same exception.

Comment: My only guess now would be that there is no Company reference on the InternalCustomers, so when it tries to figure out the tree for both, one has it hard-coded and the other has the join, so maybe it doesn't like that.  What happens if you manually do the join in the External query instead of relying on the navigation property?

Comment: It's definitely a bug, don't waste your time if it's not critical. The workaround is to provide *non const* value for `Company.Id`, e.g. use old style property get for `InternalCustomers` and use `var internalCompanyId = 1;
   return
    from customer in db.InternalCustomers
    select new Customer
    {
     Id = customer.Id,
     Name = customer.Name,
     Company = new Company
     {
      Id = internalCompanyId,
      Name = "Company",
     },
    };` There is no need to do that for `string` properties, just for the first value type property.

Comment: Did you mean to have `Name = customer.Company.Id` in your ExternalCustomers query?

Comment: @IvanStoev, for now, my workaround is doing a `.ToList()` on both before I `.Concat()` them. This cost me performance + it's a violation of my abstraction.

Comment: @NetMage No, that's a typo, I've fixed that in my post. Thanks.

Comment: The question is whether you have many queries like this. If this is the only one (or you have a few), we could seek for some better workaround w/o such costs. But as any bug workaround, it would require additional efforts (code).

Comment: This is the only one, I will try your answer when I'm at the office.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely a bug because you are doing nothing wrong, and also the exception is quite user unfriendly.

There is a workaround, but it requires additional coding. The trick is to use intermediate projection to "flat" data class (because the bug is somehow related to the nested `Company` projection), then `Concat` and finally apply the desired projection on the concatenated result. All this doesn't affect the final SQL query which is simple `UNION ALL` as it should be.

Here is how it looks:

```
public class CustomerRepository : IRepository<Customer>
{
    private readonly MyDbContext dbContext;

    public CustomerRepository(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IQueryable<Customer> Entities => InternalCustomersData.Concat(ExternalCustomersData).Select(CustomerSelector);

    private IQueryable<Customer> InternalCustomers => InternalCustomersData.Select(CustomerSelector);

    private IQueryable<Customer> ExternalCustomers => ExternalCustomersData.Select(CustomerSelector);

    private IQueryable<CustomerData> InternalCustomersData =>
        from customer in dbContext.InternalCustomers
        select new CustomerData
        {
            Id = customer.Id,
            Name = customer.Name,       
            CompanyId = 1,
            CompanyName = "Company",
        };

    private IQueryable<CustomerData> ExternalCustomersData =>
        from customer in dbContext.ExternalCustomers
        select new CustomerData
        {
            Id = customer.Id,
            Name = customer.Name,       
            CompanyId = customer.Company.Id,
            CompanyName = customer.Company.Name,
        };

    private static readonly Expression<Func<CustomerData, Customer>> CustomerSelector = data => new Customer
    {
        Id = data.Id,
        Name = data.Name,
        Company = new Company
        {
            Id = data.CompanyId,
            Name = data.CompanyName,
        }
    };

    private class CustomerData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Annoying, but works.